# Normal distributed problem

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

There is given that a car has to be repaired after riding 5000 km with it. The driver rides on average 40 km/day with a standard deviation of 7 km/day. The question is how many days can the driver ride with the car so that the chance of riding more kilometers than suggested is <0.01?

My thought process was that you find the $X_n \sim (40, 7^2/n)$ with $n$ being the amount of days and thus unknown. In the standardnormal table we can find that <0.1 equals -2.31.

So we know that $(L - 40)/(7/\sqrt n) = -2.31$. However, we have two unknown variables now. My assumption is that you can rewrite L as 5000/n — maybe?

The answer on the question is 120, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_n$ is the mean ride based on your definition. So, it should be larger than the mean ride if you were to reach $5000$ kms, i.e. $5000/n$. So, the probability of interest is
$$p=P\left(X_n>\frac{5000}{n}\right)=P\left(Z>\overbrace{\frac{5000/n-40}{7/\sqrt{n}}}^{f(n)}\right)=1-\Phi\left(f(n)\right)$$

You should find the largest $n$ that satisfies $p< 0.01$, i.e. $$\Phi(f(n))>0.99\rightarrow f(n)>\Phi(0.99)\approx 2.325$$
It'll be $120$.

Comment: That clears up a lot, thank you.